# When is it ok to create a contraction of words followed by “s”?

Tags: grammaticality, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

When is it correct to create a contraction of words followed by *is*? For instance is *who’s* a correct short form of *who is*?

Comment: or even "who was"?

Comment: @Robert: I think "who has" but not "who was"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word "is" can always be contracted, provided it is not stressed - though this is considered somewhat informal.

So, in informal contexts,

> Fred is taller than Jim.

can be shortened to

> Fred's taller than Jim.

...it doesn't depend on what word comes before "is". But if the *is* is emphatic:

> Fred **is** taller than Jim.

then it would be wrong to contract that to

> * Fred**'s** taller than Jim.

That is probably fairly obvious - if you are stressing a particular word, it doesn't pay to shorten it. But there are also other situations where the *is* has the emphasis, for instance

> I don't know what it is.

cannot be contracted to

> * I don't know what it's.

even though

> I don't know what it is doing.

*can* be reduced to

> I don't know what it's doing.

Comment: psmears, i like your answers !

Comment: @n0nChun Thank you, it's nice to be appreciated :-)

Comment: I think in ordinary, non-emphatic *speech* (but not writing unless it is intending to mimic speech), it's not so much that you "can" contract *is*, but rather that speakers practically always do.

Comment: @psmears, Why can't ""*I don't know what it is.*"" be reduced?

Comment: @Pacerier: As it says in the answer, you can't contract/reduce "is" when it is stressed. In "I don't know what it is", the word "is" is stressed, so you can't contract it.

Comment: I agree with your answers, but I'm still compelled to ask "says who?" In other words, your answer would be a lot better if it included sources.

Answer (score 1):

*Who's* is the correct contraction of *who is*, in the same way *let's* is the contraction of *let us*.

There are no grammatical rules about not using *'s* as a contraction of *is*.
In some cases, there could be a confusion between *'s* used as contraction of *is*, and *'s* used as possessive, but the rest of the sentence should clarify which is the exact meaning of the contraction.

> Geraldine's back
>   Barak's thinking