# Bob's vs. Bobs?

Tags: apostrophe, contractions

Many of my friends use an apostrophe-S after a proper noun to conjoin the word with the word *is*. For example:

> "Bob's angry today."

This does not make sense to me. I know that an apostrophe can be used to either show possession or to replace letters in a conjoined word such as "can't"; however, when you are referring to a proper noun, would that not be incorrect, since it would be showing possession instead?

Comment: "Bob is angry today" ==> "Bob's angry today".  The rule you're thinking of actually goes the other way, for most pronouns, where the possessive has no apostrophe while the contraction with "is" does.

Comment: Your friends are correct to do this.

Comment: sounds like "boobs". :-D

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it ok to create a contraction of words followed by “s”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16797/when-is-it-ok-to-create-a-contraction-of-words-followed-by-s)

Answer (score 1):

You are quite correct that the apostrophe-S combination can be used for either possession or to replace letters in a contraction.  There is no restriction that it *must* mean possession when it is used in conjunction with a proper name, though.

When used with a proper noun, if it is standing alone, then the apostrophe-S is ambiguous; "Bob's" could mean "belonging to Bob" or "Bob is".  You have to rely on the context to determine what is meant:

> Bob's angry today.
>   *"Bob's" = "Bob is"*
>
> Bob's anger gets him in trouble.
>   *"Bob's" = "belonging to Bob".*